# Android - Can't import data from internal storage to /data/data/{package_name}

Tags: java, android, database

I'm trying to allow my app's data to be transferred from one phone to another.

The content of the application is backed up by Google's backup, this backup:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

But the recovery of the data does not work when the user recovers the data on his new phone with Samsung Switch and not with the Google recovery.

Therefore I want to allow the user to save the data on his storage, transfer it to the new phone and import it into the application.

I was able to save all the app data and files to the phone's internal storage
in Documents//backup
**But I can't recover the files**
From Documents//backup
to /data/data/{package_name}

The code I did, fails to copy the files to /data/data/{package_name}

I would appreciate your help,

What is wrong with the code?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
package com.oz.levi.core.backup;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;

import com.oz.levi.utils.Utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class LocalBackupService {
    private static String BASE_DATA_PATH = "//data//com.oz.levi//";
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    public void backup(BackupCallback callback) {
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                backupData();
                callback.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callback.onComplete();
            }
        });
    }

    public void restore(BackupCallback callback) {
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                restoreData();
                callback.onComplete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callback.onComplete();
            }
        });
    }

    private void backupData() {
        try {
            File sd = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            }
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            String currentDBPath = BASE_DATA_PATH + "databases";
            String currentAudiosPath = BASE_DATA_PATH + "app_audios";
            String backupDBPath = "//Documents//backup//";
            File sourceDBDirectory = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File sourceAudiosDirectory = new File(data, currentAudiosPath);
            File destinationDBDirectory = new File(sd, backupDBPath + "databases//");
            File destinationAudioDirectory = new File(sd, backupDBPath + "app_audios//");
            Utils.copyDirectory(sourceDBDirectory, destinationDBDirectory);
            Utils.copyDirectory(sourceAudiosDirectory, destinationAudioDirectory);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void restoreData() {
        try {
            File sd = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            }
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            String backupDBPath = "//Documents//backup//";
            File sourceDBDirectory = new File(data, BASE_DATA_PATH);
            File destinationDirectory = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
            Utils.copyDirectory(destinationDirectory, sourceDBDirectory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use double slashes. One is enough.

Comment: `"//data//com.oz.levi//"` You mean: `"/data/data/com.oz.levi/"`. But have a look at getFilesDir().

Comment: Use new File(path).exists() before you use a path then you will see that all your paths are wrong.

Comment: You are not telling about exceptions.